# VBA If Then Or Statements

Tags: excel, vba, macos

VBA beginner here. I'm trying to do a pretty simple if/then statement in VBA 2003, but I'm running into the issue.  My code reads:

```
Dim var as Integer
If var = 1 or 2 Then
    'Do stuff
Else
    MsgBox ("error")
```

I keep running into the issue with the or statement.  If I change it to var = 1, the code runs without a hitch; if I rewrite it as

```
If var = 1 or var = 2
```

then it works fine.  But as I would like to expand this, being able to write this in a more cohesive way would be great.  What am I missing? :(

Comment: If you want to use an 'or' condition you need to use the variable again. i.e. If var = 1 or var = 2 Then

Comment: You've already got several good answers, but to explain what's going on underhoodwise:  OR of two integers gives you the bitwise OR of the two values:  1 is 0001 in binary, 2 is 0010, ORing them yields 0011 or 3, so Var = 1 or 2 will be true if Var = 3

Answer (score 2):

You need to write it as:

```
If var = 1 or var = 2
```

because `or` connects two conditions, not two values that form part of the same condition.

Answer (score 2):

If you want cleaner code, you can use a `case` expression instead:

```
select case var 
    case 1, 2
        'Do stuff
    case else
        MsgBox ("error")
end select
```